# How to store/retrieve from Pinia?

Tags: pinia, nuxt3

This is about using `Pinia` in `Nuxt3`.

I am trying to get it working. Need some help.

I have this `incomplete` store (`stores/some.store.ts`) ...

```
export const useSomeStore = defineStore('SomeStore', {
  //...
});

if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useSomeStore, import.meta.hot));
}
```

I want to `store/retrieve` value from it in a page (`pages/a.vue`) ...

```
<script setup lang="ts">
  // TODO: How to store in pinia?
  // TODO: How to retrieve from pinia?
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <h3>A</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    someStore: {{ someStore }}
  </div>
</template>
```

My `nuxt.config.ts` is ...

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  imports: {
    dirs: ['stores'],
  },
  modules: [
    [
      '@pinia/nuxt',
      {
        autoImports: ['defineStore', 'acceptHMRUpdate'],
      },
    ],
  ],
})
```

How to go about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it by using these in the `defineStore` ...

```
  1. id
  2. state
  3. getters
  4. actions
```